# MediaWiki breaks when I put C++ code in preformatted text

Tags: mediawiki

I want to use MediaWiki to document a C++ coding project. I am dropping code snippets into a preformatted text block. The problem is, when I include a line of code like:

if(x == y)

it breaks the page.
I'm assuming the parser thinks is markup opening heading with no matching close.

Is there a way to mark the == so that it isn't taken as markup. Haven't been able to find a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Activate [SyntaxHighlight](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight) in your `LocalSettings.php` with `wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );`. make sure `/path/to/extensions/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/pygments/pygmentize` has execution permissions and wrap your code snippets with `<syntaxhighlight lang="C++">...</syntaxhighlight>`,

OR

wrap your snippets with `<pre>...</pre>`,

OR

indent every line of your snippets with at least one space.

Comment: I will try the <syntaxhighlight> tag. The block is already indented so that I get the code in a shaded block when it displays. I tried the <pre> tag, with no success. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the <syntaxhighlight> tags. But they don't fix the problem. The keywords are colored, the highlighting is working, but it doesn't get rid of the problem caused by the double equal sign.

Comment: Is your code snippet a parametre to any template?

Comment: My code is: void Led::init(byte defaultState)
{
  init();
  if (defaultState == HIGH) {
    on();
  }
  else {
    off();
  }
}